# Introducing the PPCG Podcast!

Tags: discussion

A long time ago, in a chat room far, far away, there was an idea proposed for a PPCG Podcast, featuring members of the site talking about PPCG- and programming-related things. Due to time issues, the podcast project never really got off the ground.

Recently, I took it upon myself to revive the project, as a monthly podcast. We had an excellent first episode, which is now ready for your consumption! Download links (as well as a list of episodes) can be found at the bottom of this post.

I am always looking for feedback, so please do not hesitate to leave feedback here (as an answer) or in the [PPCG Podcast chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48368/ppcg-podcast). If you have a topic proposal or wish to be a guest, please use the chatroom for that - the comments and answers here would get too cluttered otherwise.

---

### Episodes

- Episode 0: Mego, DJMcMayhem, Doorknob, Nick Clifford (Topics: Spectre and Meltdown, Net Neutrality, Programming Language Trends and Development, PPCG v2): [mp3](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GmfQEQ1gT22TPHH2EfWWe-Uzx0vp9QI8) [ogg](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Qr8OKWf4fFmhrNDP3ZDVJRoxZLqyb8Qw) [wma](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1987r2vciSQkMz1axfNHkZTwAgZHy7kpU) [YouTube](https://youtu.be/IAEO1h5Y05c)

Comment: Not to take away from you but as Mego knows I am going to host a bi-weekly version of the podcast with a rotating group of speakers. They will not overlap in times.

Comment: @Christopher2EZ4RTZ why? We have one perfectly good one already.

Comment: @riker because a very long reason I don't have time to explain.

Comment: @Christopher2EZ4RTZ you have plenty of time.... there's no limit on when you need to reply to my comment or anything. If it's too long there's chat.

Comment: Some feedback: hosting on Google Drive is not optimal because it is difficult to accurately jump to different time stamps, compared to say youtube. I also feel like 1.5h of podcast is a bit long, I would prefer 30 minutes to an hour max (that's only my preference though)

Comment: @Fatalize Google Drive is quite convenient for hosting. I'll upload it to YouTube soon. 90 minutes ended up being the perfect time for us to get through the 4 topics chosen. Other episodes may vary in length.

Comment: @Fatalize A YouTube video has been uploaded.

Comment: @Mego Great, thanks!

Comment: Did you guys all record the parts seperately or did you all get together?

Comment: @NoOneIsHere We did the podcast live over Discord, with each of us recording our own individual parts. I synced the tracks and exported it as a single audio file.

Comment: +0 for a sensible starting number

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't allow comments on the YouTube video?

Comment: @EsolangingFruit YouTube comment sections are a cesspool. I'd rather have the commentary here.

Comment: Is this ever going to happen again?

Comment: @EsolangingFruit I would like to, but we'd need time and a few good subjects to discuss.